# Reset Google Chrome Extension Background page variables

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created Google Chrome Extension.
I have some state variables in my background page's script file (background.js)

After closing and reopening my browser, the values of that variables doesn't reset.
How can i reset that variables after closing the browser.

Comment: Do you have the `background` permission declared?

Comment: Sounds like you have the [`background` permission](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html#bg) specified, which "*makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome.*"

Answer (score 1):

If js variables in the background page keep their values, that means the chrome process has not exited. Probably some chrome window is still open. Maybe you have developer tools for the background page open?

If don't find any chrome window that's still open, check for the chrome process using task manager if you are using windows, or with ps in other environments. If the process is still running there maybe something that's preventing from ending properly.

Comment: finally i found it. i must to call 
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowId) {
    
});

Answer (score -1):

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowId) {
    Init(); });

function Init() {    //clear variables }
```

Comment: This runs your reset code whenever *any* window is closed. If the user has multiple windows open and closes one, your background page will reset.